# Order randomly distributed data into regular grid

Tags: python

I am trying to order data scattered over the globe on a regular lat/lon grid.
I could go through all the data and check to which grid cell they belong and then append them to a list for each cell. This approach seems to me long and not very efficient.

I am sure that this is not a new problem, but I have not been able to find a solution on the web. Does anyone has a suggestion or can point me to an example or tutorial?

Comment: How big is the dataset? Depending on the scale this can be either a Python data structure exercise or a deeper dive into big data. Also, could you give an example of the data so that it is easier to see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The data set can be quite large, it can go into the million, if I want to. The data would be lat,lon,data1,data2,... that is also adjustable. I currently have the data in numpy arrays, every variable in a separate one, but they can also be combined.

Answer (score 0):

I believe geohashing would be useful, in this particular case you could use [Morton number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morton_number_%28number_theory%29). This blog titled ["Spatial Keys – Memory Efficient Geohashes"](http://karussell.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/spatial-keys-memory-efficient-geohashes/) has example implementation, it's in Java, but Python version isn't much different.

```
long hash = 0;
double minLat = minLatI;
double maxLat = maxLatI;
double minLon = minLonI;
double maxLon = maxLonI;
int i = 0;
while (true) {
    if (minLat  midLat) {
            hash |= 1;
            minLat = midLat;
        } else
            maxLat = midLat;
    }

    hash <<= 1;
    if (minLon  midLon) {
            hash |= 1;
            minLon = midLon;
        } else
            maxLon = midLon;
    }

    i++;
    if (i < iterations)
        hash <<= 1;
    else
        break;
}
return hash;
```

The advantage of the Morton code is that you can calculate less bits (less iteration above) for bigger grid, more bits for finer grid. Or have fine grained codes calculated and just use prefixes for bigger grid.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I will give it a try and let you know how it works :)